# Can I use an aggregate initializer to return a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, return, anonymous

I have a function returning a named struct consisting of two ints, as follows:

```
struct myStruct {int i; int j;};

myStruct myFunction(int myArg){
    switch (myArg) {
    case 0: return {1,2};
    case 1: return {2,3};
    default: return {4,5};
    }
}
```

I want to be able to return the appropriately initialised struct from my switch statement.
I can do this by declaring a named struct and initialising it, then returning the named struct,
but it would be cleaner if I could have the compiler created anonymous structs for me as in my example above - which does not compile.
Can this be made to work (legitimately)? Or what is the cleanest way to achieve my goal?

Comment: That should work, provided your compiler supports C++11.

Comment: I dont really get your problem why you dont want to use named structs o.O How would you access the returned data?

Comment: Do you want `std::pair`?

Comment: The code you've posted is legal; are you getting compiler errors? If so, post those errors as well as compiler version.

Comment: you could simply enable C++11 or write a function make_myStruct().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly valid *C++11* code if we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `6.6.3` *The return statement* paragraph *2* says:

> A return statement with a braced-init-list initializes the object
>   or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer list.

and it provides the following example:

```
[ Example:
  std::pair<std::string,int> f(const char* p, int x) {
   return {p,x};
 }
—end example ]
```

we can see from a [a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/735ddc77be9dc777) that it works but it will not work pre- *C++11* as we can see from this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f34580798118679c).

If you are using `gcc` or `clang` and you can not use *C++11* for some reason you have the option of using [compound literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) as an extension in *C++* even though it is a *C99* feature and as we can see from this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0a9343b5d17e41b) `gcc` warns:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals [-Wpedantic]

Another option is to add constructors to your struct:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int i; int j;
    myStruct() : i(0), j(0) {} ;    
    myStruct(int x, int y) : i(x), j(y) {} ;
};

myStruct myFunction(int myArg){
    switch (myArg) {
    case 0: return myStruct(1,2) ;
    case 1: return myStruct(2,3) ;
    default: return myStruct(4,5) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding a constructor?

```
struct myStruct
{
    int i;
    int j;
    myStruct(int x, int y) {i = x; j = y;}
    myStruct() {} // still want this, otherwise "myStruct x;" won't compile
};
myStruct myFunction(int myArg){
    switch (myArg) {
    case 0: return myStruct(1,2);
    case 1: return myStruct(2,3);
    default: return myStruct(4,5);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP explicitely wants aggregate initializers

Comment: -1 The OP clearly states he wants aggregate initialization to work, which means `myStruct` must remain an aggregate. Also, your default constructor leaves members uninitialized, and the other one doesn't use initialization lists.

Comment: He states that he wants clean code as opposed to setting up the fields separately in each case clause. So what if the default constructor is empty, simple `struct myStruct{int i;int j;}` doesn't initialize anything either, I don't see anyone getting upset about that.

Comment: Well, if you value-initialize the aggregate version the data members get zero initialized. With your version, they don't. I would fix the default constructor at the very least.